# German umlaut in search query string (example Yelp)

Tags: search, encoding, character-encoding, localization

how do I replace a german umlaut in search strings (example Yelp)?
Unfortunately, not all sites treat **"ü" as "ue"** the same way

Use case: **search query input** for a web crawler is not recognized as intended.

Example:

- Original search string: Asiatische Fusionsküche
- Modified search string: Asiatische Fusionskueche
- Stuttgart, Baden-Wuerttemberg
- site: yelp.de
- ----> does return different results! (or better: no results)

---

I tried already:

**1) ü in UTF**

- --> \u00fc
- --> U+00FC

Was used like this:

- String: "Asiatische Fusionsk\u00fcche"
- String: "Asiatische FusionskU+00FCche"

**2) ü in HTML**
ü

```html
String: "Asiatische Fusionsk&uuml;che"
```

---

Any advice from experts?

Thanks
J.

Comment: I would advice to read about the Apache Lucene search engine and how it works - they can handle a lot of special things: https://lucene.apache.org/